# Why does embedding webpack into index.html gives me an unexpected token error?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I have tried to add Webpack to my vue project to use the `require.context`, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

When I run my project I get these errors:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

*and*

> Error in mounted hook:
>
> TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function

The "Unexpected token" error comes from embedding Wepback in `index.html` with the script tag. But when I delete it the error goes away.

Here's the code:

###### webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ]
};
```

###### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/hcp1kvq.css">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <base href="/" />
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
    <script src="../dist/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

###### Art.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Art</h1>
    <ArtImage :key="key" v-for="(img, key) in images" :link="imageDir + key.substr(1)" />
     <div :key="key" v-for="(img, key) in images" >
       <img :src="imageDir + key.substr(1)" class="" >
     </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ArtImage from "../components/ArtImage.vue"
export default {
  components: {
    ArtImage,
  },
    data() {
    return {
      imageDir: "../assets", // you know this already just from directory structure
      images: {}
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.importAll(require.context(this.imageDir, true, /\.png$/))
  },
  methods: {
    importAll(r) {
      var imgs = {}
      r.keys().forEach(key => (imgs[key] = r(key)))
      this.images = imgs
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: Obviously the script you are linking to is not found, structure of the 404 (not found) page is HTML which is why when it runs the script, it starts with `<!DOCTYPE html`> or something, throwing the syntax error. Problem: check where you're linking the script to in `index.js`.

Comment: @ParkingMaster thats my index.js code, I copied it from a tutorial page so I don't exactly understand where it links to. import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})